# Latex font catalog heuristic font error

Tags: miktex, ctan

I was using my latex file normally, but I formatted my PC and when I installed miktex and testudio again, this error message appeared.

!pdfTeX error: pdflatex.exe (zut_5b7xz5.enc file): cannot open encoding file for reading

I believe it is something related to the heuristic source that I use in my file. I updated miktex several times, but it didn't help.

Then I decided to create a minimal example that demonstrated this error, but another one appeared in the error log, this one:

!pdfTeX error: pdflatex.exe (file zut_geqeyh.enc): cannot open encoding file fo
r reading

I also took the code from the font catalog and copied it, thinking that mine might be in the wrong order, but the error persists.

When I remove the code from my minimal example my file compiles normally, as can be seen in my MWE.

It seems to me that I have to insert some file manually. Can someone help me please.

Follow my minimal

Comment: in texlive the file would be `/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/fonts/enc/dvips/heuristica/zut_5b7xz5.enc`  it should be in an equivalent place in miktex, if you have updated and it is not there you should raise that with the mikex issues tracker

Comment: I use miktex and texstudio here. Other files that do not have this font added open. I believe there is a file missing from this source. I've even downloaded the files for this font from CTAN, which is also available at The LaTeX Font Catalog

Comment: the files must all be in the ctan sources (as texlive has them) but there may be an issue with the miktes packaging, I can't check from here

Comment: miktex installed the enc-files into the wrong place, they are in fonts/map instead of fonts/enc

Comment: Maybe I'd better prepare a minimal example of my MWE file. A moment

Comment: you don't need to show  a MWE here, simply report to miktex (https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex-packaging/issues) that the enc-files in the package are in the wrong folder.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much, I will let you know